# Unique formula, to automatically add category of exercises from different columns into one list

Tags: google-sheets

I had a bunch of exercises listed on a sheet named 'exercise sheet', each in its own category. On a different sheet (my programming sheet), I used the formula

```
=unique('exercise list'!B3:B)
```

to pull out the category type once from that exercise sheet. see screenshots.

However, I then wanted to make the exercise categories separate, in different columns, to organise the exercise types better.

I cannot find a way to achieve the same thing I was doing. What is the new formula?? it should be `=unique('exercise list'!B3:B...)` but then I also need it to look in all the other columns, how do I type that as a formula? I need it to look in e3:3, h3:h etc.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

So far, I have made it work as one vertical list, but not been able to make it work when I have separate column lists yet.

ad

[image]

[image]

---

successfully used a flatten function. however, as you can see it is including blank cells now. how do i stop this? do i need to use a filter function? how can i include it in the formula, i can't seem to get it right.

ad

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTtmg.png)

Comment: Adam, first, images aren't terribly helpful, as the volunteer contributors here would need to enter all of your data into their own spreadsheet (guessing at locations at that) before they could even begin to think about solutions; and that will be a deterrent to most from the outset. So as a starting point, I invite you to share a link to the spreadsheet (or to a copy of it). In addition, your goal is not clear from your post (though perhaps it will be if you share a link to the spreadsheet).

Comment: You are also replying to your own posts rapidly, which from the main listing page, makes it look like you are receiving answers from others; and that will cause most people to pass by your post, assuming someone else is already on it.

Comment: Finally, it appears from this post and your other post that you are trying to build a full *system*. Stack is a free forum designed to share information or provide "small help" on single formulas or lines of code that are well-researched, well-constructed and almost correct. The forum is not designed to be a place where people can get complex, customized, time-intensive development at no cost. Just keep that in mind as you proceed with posts, so that your expectations and planning are realistic.

Comment: i've built the system, it took me a couple hours. I am nearly there, I am trying to call categories from one page to another without blank cells. I don't want blank cells, I don't want duplicates.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jX5J-4A1ENU53gBDd0463vAVAdE86vPGVuhoIXbcmTc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

It's still not entirely clear to me where you want a formula. I *think* you want it in 'Programme Sheet'!C8. If that is the case, delete that formula and replace it with the following:

`=UNIQUE(QUERY({'Exercise split into columns (not working)'!B3:B;'Exercise split into columns (not working)'!E3:E;'Exercise split into columns (not working)'!H3:H;'Exercise split into columns (not working)'!J3:J;'Exercise split into columns (not working)'!M3:M;'Exercise split into columns (not working)'!P3:P;'Exercise split into columns (not working)'!S3:S;'Exercise split into columns (not working)'!V3:V;'Exercise split into columns (not working)'!Y3:Y}, "WHERE Col1 Is Not Null ORDER BY Col1"))`

Note that "lower glute" will not be included in the list currently, since the 'Exercise split into columns (not working)' sheet does not contain that category right now.

Answer (score 0):

### QUERY

Use the [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) function to select only those rows that are not Null. Can written as **`"is not null"`**  or alternatively **`"<> ''"`**

```
=QUERY(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(
   range1,range2, [range...])),
   "Select Col1 where Col1 is not null")
```